# What exactly does "tid" do in this code snippet, does it call out the thread id?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

Can someone help me understand how this code works, when i ran this on a jupyter notebook , this gave me a syntax error. Python 2.7x
Any help this would be much appreciated.

```
def work(tid):
    with open(f"{tid}/test.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        test_1 = f.read().strip().split("\n\n")
```

Comment: Please try to format your code using the ``` helper syntax. Also, tid looks like its a folder name in the working directory given to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code that you are using `f"{tid}/test.txt"` this is an f string that can be used only on python3.6 and above and you are using python 2.7x.
In python less then 3.6 you can use `"{}/test.txt".format(tid)`.